# how to access ID3D11DepthStencilView from unreal engine device using c++

Tags: unreal-engine4

I am doing some research work on unreal engine and getting some problem.

I am successful in getting unreal engine device using c++ code.

My aim is to get ID3D11DepthStencilView from unreal engine device.

I am using OMGetRenderTargets() method to get it but method always returning null.

My code :-

```
ENQUEUE_UNIQUE_RENDER_COMMAND_THREEPARAMETER(FGETDEVICE
                                          , void **, NATIVEDEVICE, &NativeDevice 
                                          , ID3D11RenderTargetView **, ppRenderTargetViews, &m_ppRenderTargetViews
                                          , ID3D11DepthStencilView **, ppDepthStencilView, &m_ppDepthStencilView
                                          , {
                                              if ((*NATIVEDEVICE) == NULL)
                                              {
                                                (*NATIVEDEVICE) = RHIGetNativeDevice();

                                                ID3D11DeviceContext* pDeviceContext = nullptr;

                                                ((ID3D11Device *)(*NATIVEDEVICE))->GetImmediateContext(&pDeviceContext);

                                                pDeviceContext->OMGetRenderTargets(1, &(*ppRenderTargetViews), &(*ppDepthStencilView));
                                              }
                                            });
```

I want to know if i m doing something wrong?

Also, if there is another way to get depth info of unreal engine scene please share data/links/suggestion.

Comment: You can't just use a [Postprocess Material](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-us/Engine/Rendering/PostProcessEffects/PostProcessMaterials) and get the SceneDepth there?

Comment: @theodox can you share some code how to do that??? or some steps to do that???

Comment: the link in my comment goes to the UE docs for postprocess materials. Those are made with the regular UE shader graph ; the `scene_depth` node allows you to sample depth for shader purposes.   You can also check out [this article](http://www.tomlooman.com/the-many-uses-of-custom-depth-in-unreal-4/) on the custom depth buffer.

Comment: ... although both of those are shader related. Do you actually want to do something in C++ with the depth info? Or was that just the way that you wanted to get at the buffer?

Comment: @theodox sorry for late response....

Comment: Yes i need the depth info for some processing purpose. taking it from device is fast option i guess. i need actual buffers and i m not finding it through custom depth buffer. can you guided me how to take buffer data using custom depth buffer.

Comment: enlighten me plz, i am on same boat , need depth buffer from back buffer directly to send it to other application.